# Transactional SHFileOperation

Tags: winapi

Can I make the function call `SHFileOperation` a transactional one?

I mean, I want to move/copy/delete few files using this function and want to ensure that entire file operation either fully succeeds or fully fails (leaves no change).

Comment: The answer to your question is that SHFileOperation and IFileOperation are not transactional.

Comment: Maybe you could abuse the IFileOperation callback sink and manually perform the operations?

Comment: SHFileOperation is a higher level API designed for applications like Explorer. In app code, one should use the normal file API which provides transactions.